# Could not broadcast input array from shape (8,8,3) into shape (8,8,2048,3)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

So, I am again trying to run this Inception v3 fine tuning with keras, i think there is some problem with the arrays. I've already seen the other posts on these topics, but now i don´t know what to do. I don't have a lot of experience. So any help would be appreciated.

Here is the entire code https://github.com/c3s4grod/PecuScope

And this is the error that appears:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:\Users\Shangai\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\PSAI\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py",
>   line 578, in get
>       inputs = self.queue.get(block=True).get()   File "C:\Users\Shangai\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\PSAI\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
>   line 644, in get
>       raise self._value   File "C:\Users\Shangai\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\PSAI\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
>   line 119, in worker
>       result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))   File "C:\Users\Shangai\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\PSAI\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py",
>   line 401, in get_index
>       return _SHARED_SEQUENCES[uid][i]   File "C:\Users\Shangai\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\PSAI\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py",
>   line 1034, in **getitem**
>       return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)   File
>   "C:\Users\Shangai\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\PSAI\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py",
>   line 1442, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
>       batch_x[i] = x ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (8,8,3) into shape (8,8,2048,3)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:/Users/Shangai/PycharmProjects/PSai/INCEPTION.py", line 234, in
>   
>       validation_steps=steps_test)   File "C:\Users\Shangai\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\PSAI\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py",
>   line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Shangai\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\PSAI\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py",
>   line 1315, in fit_generator
>       initial_epoch=initial_epoch)   File "C:\Users\Shangai\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\PSAI\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py",
>   line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Shangai\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\PSAI\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 2194, in fit_generator
>       generator_output = next(output_generator)   File "C:\Users\Shangai\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\PSAI\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py",
>   line 584, in get
>       six.raise_from(StopIteration(e), e)   File "", line 2, in raise_from StopIteration: could not broadcast input array from shape
>   (8,8,3) into shape (8,8,2048,3)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your input tensor has not the correct size.
In general broadcasting only works if both arrays / tensors have the same number of dimensions. In your case that is not true:

```
8 8 3       -> dim = 3
8 8 2048 3  -> dim = 4
```

You need to expand the first array and add an axis with size 1 at the right position:

```
8 8 1    3
8 8 2048 3
```

Now the sizes of each axis match and for the 3. dimension broadcasting is possible.
To achieve this you can use the *newaxis*- or *None*-notation.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.ones((8, 8, 3))
B = np.ones((8, 8, 2048, 3))
C = A + B # Fails
A = A[:, :, np.newaxis, :]
C = A + B # Works
```

Another possibility is to use the function *numpy.expand_dims*.
The same notation is available for tensors in *keras* / *tensorflow* (i.e.  *tensorflow.newaxis*, *tensorflow.expand_dims*).

Comment: You are right! Ty. Now i see what i did wrong. Turns out that i needed to set "include top=True".

Comment: But another error appeared tho... Something with the tupples, it shows StopIteration: tuple index out of range

Comment: This is a very common error which can occur at a lot of places. If you have a question, try to create a minimal example [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]. In the first step, this does help yourself (and others) to understand the problem and find a solution.